# Is the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ from $0$ to $1$ known to be irrational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, transcendental-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Is it known whether $$\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} \, dx$$ is irrational? It is well-known that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ which is irrational, but what about the prior integral? Also, I know there is probably no nice "closed-form" number as its solution (ala Tim Chow).

This question arises from looking at Catalan's constant, denoted by $G$ on Wikipedia. One integral representation of $G$ is $$\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x} \, dx$$ and it looks like the integrand function on this interval, $[0,1]$, can be approximated by a bell-type curve:$$f(x)=e^{-ax^{2n}}$$ where say $a,n \in \mathbb{Q}.$

P.S. Since $$\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} \, dx+\int_1^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx,$$ at least one of the two integrals on the LHS must be irrational.

Edit: Using Desmos, I found that if $a=\frac{1}{4.1}$ and $n=0.8486609$, then $$H(n) = \left|\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x} \, dx-\int_0^1 e^{-ax^{2n}} \, dx \right| = 3.975\times10^{-9}.$$

And this function has a zero, but it seems unless the zero $n$ is a familiar algebraic number, it might not be too helpful. But perhaps it can be used to generate some type of sequence.

Comment: Previous discussions include https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783342/471884, expectedly not very illuminating.

Comment: Just to note: $$\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}.$$

Comment: @mathworker21 Go right ahead. But I'm not sure what you mean. If you show the erf() integral is irrational that would make progress.

Comment: @MatthewAlbano Check the standard method of proving that $e$ is irrational. It applies in exactly the same way to mathworker21's series.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay are you sure? I believe these $2n+1$ ruin it, because the denominator grows faster than the error term.

Comment: @CommandMaster  You are right. It isn't so simple as I thought.

Comment: Write $X=\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\,dx$.
Replacing $x$ by $\frac1x$ yields
$X=\int_1^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2}\,dx$.
Integrating by parts, we obtain $X=\frac12\left(\frac1e+\int_1^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)$.
Since $\int_1^\infty=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2-X$ we end up with
$
X=\frac13\left(\frac1e+\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\right).
$
If that is rational, then $1,e$ and $e\sqrt\pi$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$, which I doubt.

Comment: @Echo That substitution doesn't seem correct, numerically it's a completely different number

Comment: According to sage the indefinite integral is $\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)$ and the definite integral is $\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}\left(1\right)$

Comment: @joro But in a sense, the $\sqrt{\pi}$ only occurs because of the choice of normalization of $\mathrm{erf}$, to make it tend to 1 at infinity.

Comment: I have verified that the continued fraction expansion does not terminate in the first 10,000 terms.  This places a strong lower bound on the denominator of a rational expression.  (I forget how this argument goes exactly.)

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, how about this one: Write $X=\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\,dx$.
Replacing $x$ by $\frac1x$ yields
$X=\int_1^\infty x^{-2} e^{-x^2}\,dx$.
Integrating by parts, we obtain $X=\frac{2+\sqrt\pi}4$.

Comment: @Echo No, it still doesn't match numerically.  The correct value is about 0.746824132812427.

Comment: If I understand my continued fraction theory correctly, any representation as $A/B$ with integer $A,B$ has $B>10^{5000}$.

Comment: By continued fraction computation, neither $X=\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}$ nor $\mathrm{erf}(1)=2X/\sqrt\pi$ is a rational number with a denominator less than $10^{10000}$.

Comment: @te4 I might be missing something obvious, but could you explain how $e^{-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!}$ is an E-function? According to Wikipedia, $\int_0^x{e^{-t^2} dt}$ being an E-function implies its derivative also is one, but the sum doesn't seem to match the form of an E-function, and if you space it with zeros then you need to have $c_{2n} = \frac{n!}{2n!}$, whose denominator grows too quickly. Perhaps you can look at $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{(2n+1) n!}$, but it doesn't seem to be the solution of any nice ODE.

Comment: @Command note that the coefficients $a_n=1/((2n+1)n!)$ are clearly $P$ recursive since $(2n+1)a_n=(2n+3)(n+1)a_{n+1}$ so the function satisfies a linear ODE with polynomial coefficients (coefficients being polynomials over the rationals) and so does any composition with algebraic functions that makes sense (eg f(z^2)) - I am not well versed about the theory of $E$ functions which I understand have extra arithmetic conditions, so the question remains, but our function satisfies an ODE which is easily found out by identifying coefficients- degree $2$ from the P recurrence form, or at most $3$

Comment: @Conrad oh, yes, it satisfies $2f(x) + (6+4x)f'(x) + 4xf''(x) = 0$, so if we look at $f(x), f'(x)$ then they satisfy the linear equations $f'(x) = f'(x), f''(x) = -\frac{1}{2x} f(x) - (1 + \frac{3}{2x}) f'(x)$, so it does seem like the Siegel–Shidlovsky theorem is applicable (since the arithmetic conditions are satisfied), although I'm not 100% sure how to prove $f(x), f'(x)$ are algebraically independent as functions, it might be provable from $\textrm{erf}$ not being elementary.

Comment: I'm surely missing something... why doesn't the standard method for proving that $e$ is irrational fail? The remainder series is alternating, so the sum is strictly between the first two partial sums.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais yes, but the denominator of each term is $(2n+1)n!$, so a partial sum has a denominator of $n!\mathrm{lcm}(1,3,...,2n+1)$, which is greater than the error which is $(2n+3)(n+1)!$

Comment: Ah! I see what I missed! Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Following [@te4's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461028/is-the-integral-of-e-x2-from-0-to-1-known-to-be-irrational#comment1195699_461028), we can look at the function $$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt x} \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{x}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{(2n+1) n!}.$$ Note that it's an [E-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-function), because $$\log\bigl(\operatorname{lcm}(1, 3, \ldots , 2n+1)\bigr) = O(n),$$ and thus so is its derivative, $f'(x)$. We will apply the Siegel–Shidlovsky theorem to $f(x)$ and $g(x) = f'(x)$. We have the linear differential equations $$f'(x) = g(x), 
\qquad g'(x) = -\frac1{2x}f(x) - \left(1 + \frac{3}{2x}\right) g(x).$$

Since $$f'(x) + \frac{f(x)}{2x} = \frac{e^{-x}}{2x}$$ is elementary, and since $f(x)$ is non-elementary, we can conclude that $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are algebraically independent, so  the Siegel–Shidlovsky theorem tells us that $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ are algebraically independent. Hence $$f(1) = \int_0^1 {e^{-x^2} dx}$$ is transcendental, so in particular it is irrational.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. This might seem trivial for some, but I just figured out that if ${a,b}$ are algebraically independent over say $\mathbb{Q}$, then each of $a$ and $b$ individually are also algebraically independent which implies transcendental. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are not transcendental. Then there exist polynomials $P$ and $Q$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $Q(a)=0$ and $R(b)=0$. But this means we can take $P(x,y) = Q(x) + R(y)$. Then $P(a,b) = Q(a) + R(b) = 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: I just don't understand the second to last point about $2xf'(x) + f(x) = e^{-x}$ being elementary, and $f(x)$ being non-elementary implies $f(x)$ and $f′(x)$ are algebraically independent. From direct computation we also see that $f'(x)$ is non-elementary. Does it also have to do with the fact that $e^{-x}$ is a transcendental function?

Comment: @MatthewAlbano From $2xf'(x) + f(x) = e^{-x}$, if $P(f(x), f'(x)) = 0$ for some polynomial $P$, then there is a polynomial $Q$ such that $Q(f(x), e^{-x}) = 0$, which contradicts $f(x)$ being non-elementary, because the roots of a polynomial with elementary coefficients are elementary.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewAlbano your argument that $a$ and $b$ are both transcendental when $\{a,b\}$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbf Q$ is incorrect. The negation of them both being transcendental is not that they are both algebraic, but only that at least one is algebraic.

Comment: @MatthewAlbano Still, it is true that every subset of an algebraically independent set is algebraically independent, just as every subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, I know. I read it over later, but could not edit it. I was just thinking out loud, and I thought that everybody here already knew this simple fact. But it got the point across for me and thought other people would understand the basic idea and so I thought I did not need to delete it and write it over. If you want I can explain it. Consider where one of $a$ or $b$ is not transcendental (since we already did both). WLOG say it is $a$. Then there is a poly $R(x)$ over the rationals such that $R(a)=0$. Construct $P(x,y)=yR(x)$. This means $P(a,b)=bR(a)=0.$ Contradiction.

Comment: Sorry @KConrad, is this Keith Conrad from UConn? Sorry if I sounded annoyed. When I was younger I looked at your expository papers online about analytic number theory from time to time. Very good.

Answer (score 21):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}$(This answer had been posted before I saw [Command Master's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461070/36721). I am leaving it here, since it contains more and/or different details; in particular, here the argument that the function $\erf$ is non-elementary is not used.)

---

The answer is yes. Moreover, the value of the integral
\begin{equation*}
    I:=\int_0^1 e^{-t^2}\,dt 
\end{equation*}
is transcendental.

To show this, let us use some of the comments, with added details:

**Step 0:** For real $x>0$, let
\begin{equation*}
    y(x):=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt x}\,\erf\sqrt x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\frac{x^n}{n!}, 
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
    c_n:=\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}
\end{equation*}
and $y(0):=1$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    I=y(1). 
\end{equation*}

**Step 1:** The function $y$ is an [E-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-function#Definition) over $\Q$.

Indeed, of the three bulleted conditions listed in the definition of an E-function in the Wikipedia article, only the last, third one is nontrivial. To verify it, let $q_n$ be the least common multiple of $1,\dots,2n+1$. Then, in view of the prime number theorem,
\begin{multline*}
    q_n=\prod_{p\le2n+1}p^{\lfloor\log_p(2n+1)\rfloor}
    \le\prod_{p\le2n+1}p^{\log_p(2n+1)} \\ 
    =\prod_{p\le2n+1}(2n+1)=(2n+1)^{\pi_{2n+1}} \\ =(2n+1)^{(1+o(1))(2n+1)/\ln(2n+1)} \\ 
    =e^{(1+o(1))(2n+1)}=O(n^{n\varepsilon})
\end{multline*}
for each real $\varepsilon>0$, where the product $\prod_{p\le2n+1}$ is over all primes $p\le2n+1$ and $\pi_k$ is the number of primes $\le k$.

**Step 2:** Letting $y_1(x):=y(x)$ and $y_2(x):=y'(x)$, and using [Command Master's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461028/is-the-integral-of-e-x2-from-0-to-1-known-to-be-irrational#comment1195760_461028), we get the system of ODEs
\begin{equation*}
    y'_1(x)=y_2(x),\quad y'_2(x)=-\frac1{2x}\,y_1(x)-\Big(1+\frac3{2x}\Big)y_2(x). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
We now want to use the [Siegel–Shidlovsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-function#The_Siegel%E2%80%93Shidlovsky_theorem). The only possibly nontrivial condition of this theorem to check here is that the "functions" $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are algebraically independent over $\Q(x)$ or, equivalently, that the "functions"
\begin{equation*}
    v_1(t):=y_1(t^2)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2t}\,\erf t\quad\text{and}\quad  v_2(t):=y_2(t^2)=\sqrt\pi\,\frac{t\erf' t-\erf t}{2t^3}
\end{equation*}
are algebraically independent over $\Q(t^2)$. So, it is enough to show that $\erf t$ and $\erf' t$ are algebraically independent over $\Q(t)$.

To do this, suppose that
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{(j,k)\in F}P_{j,k}\,\erf^{\,j} (\erf')^k=0
\end{equation*}
for some nonempty finite subset $F$ of the set $\{0,1,\dots\}^2$ and some polynomial functions $P_{j,k}$. The latter identity can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{j=0}^m Q_j \erf^{\,j}=0 \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
for some integer $m\ge0$, where each $Q_j(t)$ is rational in $(t,\erf'(t))$ and $Q_m=1$. Differentiating \eqref{2}, we get an identity of the form \eqref{2}, but with $m-1$ in place of $m$ (if $m\ge1$). So, without loss of generality $m=0$. So, $Q_0=0$. Similarly repeatedly rewriting and differentiating, we conclude that all the coefficients of the $(\erf')^k$'s in $Q_0$ are $0$. This confirms that $\erf t$ and $\erf' t$ are algebraically independent over $\Q(t)$, and hence
$y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are algebraically independent over $\Q(x)$.

**Step 3:** By the Siegel–Shidlovsky theorem, $I=y(1)$ and $\frac1e=y'(1)+\frac12\,y(1)$ are algebraically independent. In particular, it follows that $I$ and $e$ are transcendental and hence irrational. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Why does the derivative of $y_2$ involve $y_1$? $y_2$ is elementary but $y_1$ is not!

Comment: Your formula for $y$ is not quite correct as the power series in $x$ has half the coefficients zero - it is a power series in $x^2$

Comment: @Zerox : Thank you for your comment. This has now been fixed.

Comment: @Conrad : Thank you for your comment. This has now been fixed.

Comment: that's a very nice detailed answer

Comment: @IosifPinelis thanks for this answer!

Comment: @Conrad : Thank you for your appreciation.

Comment: @mathworker21 : Thank you for your appreciation.